# Div wont center inside a another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a div that has a header and text inside another div, but it doesn't work. It just keeps on leaning to the right which isn't the way I want it to be. What is wrong with it?

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    background-color: #9C5B27;
}
.about {
    position: static;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 543px;
    text-align: center;
}
header {
    text-align: center;
}
article {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 567px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
#content {
    background-color: #574637;
    width: 649px;
    height: 134px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="about">
  <header>Home</header>
            <div id="content">
    <article>
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </article>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: That is because your `#content` is wider than the `.about` element. So it will of course not look visually centered.

Answer (score 0):

You are overflowing the `.about` container.. you can achieve the espected result with this:

```
body {
  background-color: #9C5B27;
}

.about {
  margin: 25px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  width: 650px;
  padding: 16px; 
  margin: 12px auto;
  background-color: #574637;
}

article {
  color: #fff;
}
```